# Logic behind "ĉiu"?

Tags: esperanto-speakers

In Esperanto, why does *ĉiu* mean "every" when *ĉi* serves elsewhere as a proximal prefix (e.g. *ĉi-flanke*)  and *-u* is a suffix meaning "one"? Why does this not mean "this one" just as *ti*+ *-u* means "that one"?

Answer (score 7):

No, for the *correlatives* holds: `ĉi-, ki-, ti-, neni-, i-` and `-u`, `-am`, `-el` and such are not independent parts, roots, and have nothing to do with roots `ĉi` or imperative verb suffix `-u`.

The definition of **-u** is adjective *selection of **one** of some*, with persons used as noun.

The definition of **ĉi-** is *all/every*.

The correlatives "happen" to form a table with similarities. In fact this holds
for natural languages too, to some degree.

For `ki-` the indoeuropean Q: q (Italian) / k (Russian) / w (German).
So `what, who, which, where`. The same for `ti-`: `that, there, this`.

Mind that this table of 5 x 9 is more elaborate than most languages, and not every entry has the same frequency, even
if `-u` and `ki-` serve different cases `-u` for persons too; `ki-` for both questions and subsentences. Linguists sometimes find this *not* a positive feature of Esperanto, though IMHO natural languages provide the foundation.
Ido removed the table.

And of course on may say

```
ĉiuj ĉi, ĉi ĉiuj = all these
ĉial ĉi = for all these reasons
tiu ĉi = this
```